# Auto-change or Query function Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I currently have a spreadsheet with a sheet called Data that automatically imports data and has manual data entry, which then formats it correctly in a sheet called Output. From there, it is distributed over multiple sheets through QUERY functions with formulas like this:

```
=QUERY(Output!$B$2:XY,"SELECT AB",0)
```

This works, but it brings problems when I add a new column. Total amount of columns is 70 at the moment (excluding column A which is Date). If I add a new column, for example after Z, so column AA, then all the query functions that have rows AA - beyond don't work anymore and have to be manually updated.

Is there a way to auto-change these columns, so I can add a column in data and output, without it requiring manual updating?

Please note that the Data sheet and Output sheet have identical columns but have different formatting (for example duration is in numbers, and in Output formatted with `=IF(ISBLANK(Data!AG7), ,Data!AG7/24/3600)`. All sheets have column A being the date.

Small and edited example sheet (exact same layout, just less data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wLJ1xX9-ZXfmf9NHsBl3GscVS35hHnm6vFawgxRsOMY/edit?usp=sharing

If in this sheet a row is added, say, after Duration, then column G - Q and the single Activity column will display the wrong data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

You can use `ARRAYFORMULA` with `HLOOKUP` to get the values you need:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(HLOOKUP(C14:Q14, Output!B1:Q, ROW(A2:A), FALSE)))
```

### Full answer

The main problem of your code is that you are manually selecting the import column for every single one. A nicer way of doing this is to use the header as a way of finding it.

This answer intends to be a mini-tutorial on how it works. I’ll be using the linked spreadsheet to explain it, so all the ranges may need to be changed for other spreadsheets.

#### Step 1: Using the column header to select the column in `Output`

To do so, we’ll use `HLOOKUP`. This formula finds a column with the appropriate header (first row) and then returns the value with its column and the specified row.

So if you go to `C15` and add the formula:

```
=HLOOKUP(C14, Output!B1:Q, 2, FALSE)
```

You can see that the value on this cell becomes the first value of the `Score` column on the `Output` sheet. The parameters we added:

- `C14`: The value we search, the header in this case.
- `Output!B1:Q`: The range of values we want. In this case are the headers and the values.
- `2`: The index of the cell we want on the found column. Starts with 1 (headers).
- `FALSE`: If the headers in `Output` are sorted. In this case, they are not.

#### Step 2: Extend to every row in the `C` column

Now that we have it working for a single cell, let’s extend it to multiple cells. To do so we’ll use `ARRAYFORMULA` together with `ROW`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(HLOOKUP(C14, Output!B1:Q, ROW(A2:A), FALSE))
```

What `ARRAYFORMULA` allows us to do is to set a function in a single cell but fill multiple cells. In this case we are extending it to the entire column.

But now you will realize that we need to change the index each time, that is the `2` that we had before needs to be different for every cell.

Here is where `ROW` comes into play: it returns the row number of the given cell. But we can actually ask for any cell so we start with `A2` (so it returns 2) and continue all it can. Together with `ARRAYFORMULA` it generates an array of numbers from 2 to the number of rows of the document.

#### Step 3: Repeat for each column

`ARRAYFORMULA` does not only work in one dimension. So we can extend it to other columns. Changing `C14` for the range of columns is enough:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(HLOOKUP(C14:Q14, Output!B1:Q, ROW(A2:A), FALSE))
```

#### Step 4: Filter errors

Now you’ll see some `#REF` errors. They are caused by the header not actually existing in the `Output` sheet. We can remove the errors with `IFERROR`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(HLOOKUP(C14:Q14, Output!B1:Q, ROW(A2:A), FALSE)))
```

Notice though that this forces you to have the exact same name everywhere which you may not want.

#### Step 5: Modify to your needs

This formula is the simplest I could think of, but it still needs to be maintained and tailored to where it goes. You can basically modify 2 things in the formula:

- `C14:Q14`: This range is the value to compare to generate the columns. We are using the headers but it doesn’t need to be. You can use another row even from another sheet. This could be done to have the headers with different names.
- `Output!B1:Q` This range is all the data. You’ll need to change it if you add a new row.

Notice that you cannot manually add values in the columns in the first range, so multiple formulas may actually be necessary. You only need to change the first range.

You can improve this formula and add more features to it, but it can get complex pretty quickly.

### References

- [HLOOKUP (Google’s Docs Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093375)
- [ARRAYFORMULA (Google’s Docs Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [ROW (Google’s Docs Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093316)
- [IFERROR (Google’s Docs Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)

Comment: Thank you for your very informative answer! This is indeed working well and exactly how I intended it to be.
I'm applying it to the Output sheet as well, since it has the same problem. It works, but the only thing I'm bumping into is the duration time formats, as it has a small formula: '=IF(ISBLANK(Data!C2), ,Data!C2/24/3600)', and for one special column also another formula, '=IF(Data!BL2>0, BK2+Data!BL2, (Data!BL2*-1)+BK2)'. I tried the following formula, but it failed (no info): 
'=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(HLOOKUP(AE1:AF1, Data!AE1:AF/24/3600, ROW(A2:A), 0)))'
Any idea how this could work?

Comment: @Nuxurious Operations should be performed to the result of `HLOOKUP` which returns the selected value. That means that you probably want to use `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(HLOOKUP(AE1:AF1, Data!AE1:AF, ROW(A2:A), 0)/24/3600))`. If you encounter things like that I would recommend working with a single cell, using and modifying the formula on step 1. When that works, you can easily apply the following steps to make it more general. Notice that if you only need it to work on a single column you may skip step 3.

Comment: That works, but it adds another problem: it formats the cells without data as 0:00:00 or 12:00 AM, which doesn't make the monthly averages accurate anymore. This was a problem previously, and I was able to combat it with this formula: 
'=IF(ISBLANK(Data!E2), ,Data!E2/24/3600)' but I'm not sure if you can add that formula at the end as well, since it's about specific cells. I haven't had success trying yet in the [testing sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wLJ1xX9-ZXfmf9NHsBl3GscVS35hHnm6vFawgxRsOMY/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: @Nuxurious You basically have 2 options: you can use 2 columns (one with the `ARRAYFORMULA` and the other with the `IF`) or use `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(IFERROR(HLOOKUP(D1, Data!D1:D, ROW(A2:A), 0))),,HLOOKUP(D1, Data!D1:D, ROW(A2:A), 0)/24/3600))` which is basically changing `Data!E2` for the entire formula and removing any unnecessary parts.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

instead of last column use number like:

```
=QUERY(Output!$B$2:1000, "select AB", 0)
```

Comment: That's a good idea, thank you. Do you have a suggestion how to possibly make the columns auto-update, if I would add a column after AA, so AB, it would replace the data  that function gives.

Comment: you mean like in select staement?

Comment: Yes, or a sort of filter. This is the only working formula I was able to create so far, and it works fine, but the auto-update is quite frustrating.

Comment: you could apply some math to it like: `=QUERY({Output!$B$2:1000}, "select Col"&COLUMNS(1:1), 0)` to get always the last column